# Style All Children

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Basically I have a dynamically created page like below:

```
<div id="content>
 DYNAMIC HERE
</div>
```

I have no control of what is in the div, but I know there will be a lot of tables that may be contained within other divs.

For example

```
<div id="content">
     <div >
           <div >
            TABLE HTML HERE
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

But I will never know how far down a table could be.

So I would ideally want to do something like:

```
#content table {
 style here
}
```

But this applies to all tables within that div even if they're nested many elements down.

How would I say for this div and everything within it style the tables?

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID. It is invalid, and will cause things to break.

Comment: This is besides the point, but ids should be unique.  Hopefully your sample is just using id="content" as filler?

Comment: That was a copy and paste typo sorry :)

Comment: Yes i just copy and pasted to save me writing the div code out over and over there is only one element with the id content

Comment: It's still unclear exactly which tables you want to include and which ones you want to exclude.

Comment: All tables within content must be stlyed the same

Comment: "But this doest apply to all tables with that div" — Yes, it does!

Comment: It looks like you need to UNDERSTAND css selectors before going any further. Search the web for 'css selectors explained w3c'. Here is a nice tutorial : http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the space syntax indicates that you want to select any descendants of the parent, so `#content table` is fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/XnnLG/

Comment: Darnit, beat me to it! For what it's worth, my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FAEgj/).

Comment: Ahh so what does the * selector mean then

Comment: It means *any* element. No matter what kind of element it is.

Answer (score 2):

Your current syntax is for a [Descendant Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors). Descendant selectors are similar to [child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors), but they do not require that the relationship between matched elements be strictly parent-child. Child Selectors use

```
#content > table
```

so, the syntax you have is correct for applying a style to a nested table.

An exception to this (as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17949353/1257652)) is if you have a more [specific selector](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Answer (score -1):

Using `#content table` *should* target all the tables within #content.
However, if there is a table, for example `#test` which is styled from another stylesheet, the `#test` is more specific than `#content table`, so the other style will overrule yours.

You can overrule that style using `!important` in your stylesheet, you should use that on every line, so it's not the cleanest solution.

For example:

```
#content table {
   color: green !important;
   background: red !important;
}
```